# How to create an exact SQL query in rawQuery?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, row

I have a problem, I need to extract some data from my database but I can't exactly create the SQL query exactly what I mean.
I would like to retrieve the "_id" and "NAME" from the CARS and PLANES tables when the checkbox (FAVORITE) is checked.

Please be patient, I'm just learning SQL.

By the way, if I already have a list filled up with data and I
 would like to go to the corresponding activity, how to do it if
 the list is filled with eg 2-3 activity?

***DataBaseHelper.class***

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CARS (_id INTEGER KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                       + "NAME TEXT, "
                       + "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID INTEGER, "
                       + "FAVORITE INTEGER);");

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE PLANES (_id INTEGER KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
                       + "NAME TEXT, "
                       + "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID INTEGER, "
                       + "FAVORITE INTEGER);");

          etc..
           }
          }
```

***NewActivity.class***

```
 public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    ListView listfavorites = findViewById(R.id.favorites);

 try{
       SQLiteOpenHelper helper = new DataBaseHelper(this);  
       SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

//   Now with this query, my list is filled with all the data, when I tickle
 // which object is the favorite.

 Cursor favorite = db.rawQuery ("SELECT CARS._id, PLANES._id,
 CARS.NAME, PLANES.NAME FROM CARS, 
PLANES WHERE
   CARS.FAVORITE=1 AND 
PLANES.FAVORITE=1, null);

    CursorAdapter favoriteAdapter = new 
 SimpleCursorAdapter(NewActivity.this,               
   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
 favorite,  
new String[]{"NAME",
   new int[]}{android.R.id.text1},0);

   listfavorites.setAdapter(favoriteAdapter); 

          }catch(SQLite Exception e){
          Toast.makeText(this, "Database not available", 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }


// By the way, if I already have a list filled up with data and I   
// would like to go to the corresponding activity, how to do it    if
// the    list is filled with eg 2-3 activity?    

  listfavorites.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){     

          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, Cars.class);       
             intent.putExtra(Cars.EXTRA_CAR, (int)id);     
             startActivity(intent);
           } });

              }
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is broken.  What you did will join the two tables, and will return any combo of two rows where both are favorites.  Instead, you want the UNION of two different sql queries, one getting your favorite cars and one your favorites planes.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: I have created such a query, but it still does not work, what am I doing wrong?                                                                                                               favorite = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, CARS.NAME FROM CARS WHERE CARS.FAVORITE=1 UNION SELECT _id, PLANES.NAME FROM PLANES WHERE PLANES.FAVORITE=1", null);                                     java.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist?